# Find all $(x,y,z)\in \Bbb Z^3$ so that $ x^y=x(\text{mod }z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I got this problem for Integer Triplets

I tried this way :
$ x^y=x(\text{mod }z)$

which implies

$ x^y-x=0(\text{mod }z)$

and then i got stuck, 
What should I do? is their a better way

Comment: Here's a kind of obnoxious solution.  Let $A=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z^3\mid z|(x^y-x)\}$.  Then $A$ is exactly the set of all triples $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z^3$ such that $x^y\equiv x(\text{mod }z)$.

Comment: what about non primes?

Comment: I'm confused by your question because my (obnoxious) solution doesn't mention anything about primes.

Comment: It looks like fmt and is only valid for primes ?

Comment: It does look like FLT, but this is  true for things other than primes $z$.  For example when $x=1$ this is true for all $y,z$.

Comment: Maybe they're looking for something related to the Euler $\phi$ function.

Comment: $x^{\phi(z)}\equiv 1 \pmod{z}$ but, it is not the least such number which will accomplish this. Maybe it's a step in the right direction.